# Real Analysis like convergence of Loss Functions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, convergence

Here's one thing i noticed. In Elementary Real Analysis, when we say that a sequence $s_n$ converges to a point $s$, we first set an
 $\epsilon > 0$ such that for large $N \in \mathbb{N} $
$| s_n - s | < \epsilon. $

---

EDIT: Suppose i have a sequence of loss functions $L_n(\theta)$. Where $n=iterations.$ Implementing Gradient Descent, we can find $L_(\theta)$ such that $ L_n(\theta)\to L(\theta)$ when $n>N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$

Question: Do we choose an $\epsilon$ such that $|L_n(\theta) - L(\theta)|<\epsilon$ for some $n>N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Benj Cabalona Jr.

What you are mentioning is something every algorithm uses for convergence of their loss metrics. I will list down some algorithms from sklearn for your reference

1. **Decision Tree**

**min_impurity_split** : float, (default=1e-7)

*Threshold for early stopping in tree growth. A node will split if its impurity is above the threshold, otherwise it is a leaf.*

2. **Support Vectors**

**tol** : float, optional (default=1e-3)

*Tolerance for stopping criterion.*

3. **Neural Networks**

For each loss function, one can set the stopping threshold. In Keras you have the [EarlyStopping](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) callback

Comment: Thanks Anant. That's a straightforward answer.